# How to monitor Jobs with the Prometheus Operator?

Tags: prometheus-operator

I have a need to monitor some jobs in Kubernetes.

I see two differents ways to monitor with the Operator: PodMonitor vs Service Monitor.

What would you recommend when it comes to monitoring jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nature, jobs do not have services. Instead, they generate temporary pods to run a job. This doesn't fit well into a service-based discovery of Prometheus. Thus I recommend using a `PodMonitor` for Jobs.